# Using Sat-popover inside *ngFor, angular6

Tags: angular

I am trying to use sat-popover, inside *ngFor, so that I can have multiple sat-popover instances for different buttons.

[sat-popover](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sat-popover-queryxhildren?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

It is not working. Please help me.

Comment: try something like this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/sat-popover-queryxhildren-djkmha

Comment: @Chellappan, you can see in your example that both popover are opening near second element.

Answer (score 1):

Use template ref to get the ref of the SatPopover

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren('p') allPopovers: QueryList<SatPopover>;
```

**component.html**

```
<sat-popover *ngFor="let popover of users" #p [horizontalAlign]="'before'" verticalAlign="above">
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        Username: {{ popover.username }} <br>
      Posts: {{ popover.posts }}
    </div>
  </sat-popover>


<div *ngFor="let tpl of allPopovers;let i = index"style="margin: 100px 200px;">
  <button [satPopoverAnchorFor]="tpl" (click)="tpl.toggle()">More Info-{{i+1}}</button>
</div>
```

Get rid the expression has changed error Inject ChangeDetectionRef then use the detectChanges method which will check the view and its children

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/sat-popover-queryxhildren-luwzzf

Comment: these buttons will be inside individual <tr>, so I cant use *ngFor to group buttons. These needs to be handle separately.